# make ggplot2 save several datasets to ggplot2 object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am developing a function for a package to build a relatively complex `ggplot2` plot.
This plot requires *several* dataframes.
I understand that that is possible with `ggplot2`, as in the below example – the plot looks fine.

The problem arises when I wrap such a call to ggplot2 in a function, and then have the function return the ggplot2 object (say, `g`): when I then try to print this object `g`, ggplot2 shouts at me that it can't find this or that data.
Works fine *inside* the function.

My hypotheses is that this does not work because ggplot2 saves only *one* dataset in its object.

Here's my test:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10))
library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(data = df1, aes(x=x, y=y))
g <- g + geom_point()
g <- g + geom_point(data = df2, aes(x=x, y=y))
g
print(g$data)
```

That looks fine, but `g$data` is just:

```
            x           y
1  -0.6877237 -1.04801924
2  -1.0866550  1.65779036
3  -1.7649836 -0.08788452
4  -0.6459257 -0.22692532
5   0.5649141  0.51516430
6  -0.3117237 -1.84447991
7  -0.5771836 -0.65616395
8  -0.7666694  1.44671890
9   0.1687370  0.94250971
10 -0.3278663  1.00276428
```

Looks like ggplot2 dropped the other df.

Am I getting this right?
How do I make ggplot2 remember several datasets?

Comment: this is presumably because in the initial `ggplot` function on line 1, you only have one dataframe.  The df2 only is added in a `geom_point()`

Comment: great, thank you so much @MrFlick – that solves my problem.
If you put it up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your hypothesis is wrong. ggplot will store all the data for the plot in the object, just maybe not where you think it will. If you put data in the call to `ggplot()`, it will be in the `$data` property. If you specify data in a layer, it will be included with that layer.

In your example, `df1` would be at `g$data` as you observed, and `df2` would be located at `g$layers[[2]]$data`. So both data sets are in the ggplot object.

Comment: thanks so much  @MrFlick that helped me a lot.
Should've looked into the layers first.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this gets you part of the way...

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10))

library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(data=cbind(df1, df2))
g <- g + geom_point(data = df1, aes(x=x, y=y))
g <- g + geom_point(data = df2, aes(x=x, y=y))
g
```

Gets you the same plot as before...

```
str(g)
```

But we've now made the data one dataframe.

```
List of 9
 $ data       :'data.frame':    10 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ x: num [1:10] 1.398 -0.379 0.486 0.813 1.057 ...
  ..$ y: num [1:10] 0.0499 -2.5607 0.2624 0.7812 0.5015 ...
  ..$ x: num [1:10] 1.283 -0.786 -0.223 -0.89 -0.103 ...
  ..$ y: num [1:10] -2.19 -0.468 -0.436 -2.502 -0.143 ...
```

Comment: thanks @jalapic, yeah – I thought about that, too.
Does not work in my case, because my *real* `df`s are very different, so I can't bind them.

My question is also more general about the internals of `ggplot2` – any way to make it save several dfs?